# Levenshtein (or Damerau-Levenshtein, if possible!) distance is Assembly

Tags: c#, assembly

I have a program in which I need to calculate several times the Levenshtein distance between pairs of words (one of them fixed), and several times may range from about 1000 to 120000 for every fixed word. Since I want to optimize this program as much as I can I thought about implementing these calculations in assembly. The problem is that I know nothing about assembly except for the theory and that it may represent big speed improvements. Can anyone please help me or provide me with the assembly code for this distance? Also, how can I call assembly from a C# module?

Comment: A good C compiler can produce performance close to that of assembly. Plus you can ask it to produce the intermediate assembly file for you to inspect and detect gross inefficiencies (usually caused by the compiler's fear of aliases: you can then fix them at the C level by copying some global variables to local variables to which it's clear there is no alias).

Comment: Perhaps you should implement this in C# first (or use a C# library) before learning assembly language. After all, the C# code may be fast enough for your needs.

Comment: Given that you don't know assembly, it is probably not the best choice as optimizing assembly code takes a fair bit of knowledge about both assembly and the hardware in question.

Comment: Compile it with the best c compiler you can find (the Intel compiler is supposed to be pretty good). Asm is typically faster than c if you either can't express your problem well in c (i.e. a certain intrinsic is missing) or the compiler doesn't use certain instruction sets(.net jitter and SSE for example). Compilers are damn smart, so to get better code than they do, you'll need to know a lot about asm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily use a [BK-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree) to create a lookup tree if Levenshtein is enough. Damarau-Levenshtein [can not be used with a metric tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance#Algorithm_discussion).

You dont need to write this implementation in assembler or C#, you can get far by using unsafe code and pointers.

- Read and cache `str.Length`, those are method invocations (most probably inlined/optimized)
- Access your strings with pointers.
  `fixed(char* ptrX=strX, ptrY=strY) ...`
- You can create your table/array/state as an int[rows*cols] instead of int[rows][cols] and use pointers to read/write.
  `int[] state = new int[rows*cols]`
  `fixed(int* ptrState=state)`
- You dont really need more than two rows in your state table, you have the one you read from, and the one you write to. Then swap the pointers and read from what you just wrote.
- I believe you can optimize by removing identical prefixes/suffixes
  `L('catz', 'cats') == L('z', 's') == 1`
  `L('rats', 'cats') == L('r', 'c') == 1`